# Memory Management + containers

Tags: c++

Friends

Containers have automatic memory management mechanism . 
When values are inserted using copy Constructor and when values are removed , destructor is called for each value. 
After the no of elements are read, what stage desctuctor gets called ?

How does a container class handle memory when elements are read not erased ?

Many thanks

Comment: this question doesn't make much sense in its present form, can you clarify? probably add some code and describe what is happening and what you expect to happen?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. Maybe a bit of sample code to show what you mean would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers don't have memory management, objects have memory management.

```
obj a;
{
    std::vector<obj> b;
    b.push_back( a );//copy of 'a' taken here
}//copy of 'a' in vector destructed here because the copy goes out of scope not specifically the vector

//'a' still exists
```

alternatively

```
obj* a = new obj;
{
    std::vector<obj*> b;
    b.push_back( a );
    b.push_back( new obj );//pointer of type obj taken here
}//obj destructor not called
//got a memory leak as the obj created still exists but has no reference
delete a;//but can still delete a
```

Answer (score 2):

> How does a container class handle memory when elements are read not erased ?

It doesn't. There is no memory handling to be done.

When objects are created, memory for them must be allocated, and when they are destroyed, memory must be released.

When you read an existing element, you are not creating or destroying anything, so the container doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks 
So memory gets released when container goes out of scope . or you apply erase i.e then destructor gets called .

Answer (score 0):

The objects in a container gets destructed when you explicitly erase elements and when your container goes out of scope.